# VB.NET How to Add TimeSpan for Timer Inteval

Tags: vb.net, timer, timespan

This is the scenario, I have three `NumericUpDown` for the values of second, minute and hour, And if a number is entered in the `NumericUpDown` i.e. `5`, it will be converted to `5000 ms` so my `Timer` can read it as 5 seconds. I'm trying to make a scheduler for every interval and this is my code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Label13.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Form3.NumericUpDown1.Text).TotalMilliseconds
    Label14.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Form3.NumericUpDown2.Text).TotalSeconds
    Label15.Text = TimeSpan.FromHours(Form3.NumericUpDown3.Text).TotalMinutes

    Dim times() As String = {Label13.Text, Label14.Text, Label15.Text}

    For Each time In times
        Dim interval As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(time)

            Timer1.Interval = interval
            MsgBox("hey")
    Next
End Sub
```

And it has an error at `Timer1.Interval = interval` that says `Timespan cannot be converted to Integer`, and i can't think of any way to fix this, can you help me out? TIA~!

Comment: What you want here is not so clear. Say, if your `NumericUpDown1.Text = 5`, `NumericUpDown2.Text = 15`, `NumericUpDown3.Text = 25`, how do you want it to behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

Timer1.Stop()

Timer1.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, CInt(nudMinutes.Value), CInt(nudSeconds.Value), CInt(nudMilliseconds.Value)).TotalMilliseconds

Timer1.Start()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to get you past your current error.

```
    Dim tsTest As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(NumericUpDownTest.Value)

    Label1.Text = tsTest.TotalSeconds.ToString("n0")

    Timer1.Interval = CInt(tsTest.TotalMilliseconds)
```

Start with just doing seconds and when that code works see if you can add the others.